# I'm having trouble writing a code that reads data from a text file and prints them in ascending order

Tags: c++

So far the code does read data from files and prints them but it only puts the smallest number first but organizes the rest in a weird way.
I tried using .begin() and .end() but for some reason it wont work.
I'm also just getting the hang of C++ so any feedback on the entire code is much appreciated!

```
void printVector(vector<double> arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

vector<double> readFile(string filename)
{
    vector<double> arr;
    filename = filename + ".txt";
    ifstream file(filename.c_str());
    double num = 0.0;
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while (file >> num)
        {
            arr.push_back(num);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

int sorteddata(vector<double> data) //sorting data
{
    int counter[data.size()];
    int i, j, test;
    for (i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < data.size(); j++)
        {
            if (counter[j] < counter[i])
            {
                test = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = test;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << data[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    string filename;
    int choice;
    cout << "Enter a file name to get data from: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    vector<double> arr = readFile(filename);
    cout << "Sorted data:\n";
    sorteddata(arr);
}
```

Comment: You are performing the test on the "counter" array, but swaping inside the "data" array? I am not following the purpose of the "counter" array...

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code. The most obvious issue is with `sorteddata()`

- You need to pass it as a reference as you modify the `data` inside that function.
- The additional array `counter` is incorrect and useless.

```
int sorteddata(vector<double> &data) //sorting data
{
    // int counter[data.size()];  //<-- remove this, and just use data directly
    int i, j, test;
    for (i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < data.size(); j++)
        {
            if (data[j] < data[i])
            {
                test = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = test;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << data[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing `counter`. It is not needed for the sort algorithm you've chosen.  Compare `data[j] < data[i]` to see if you need to swap in `sorteddata`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream inputData,inputData1; 
    inputData.open("Test1.txt",ios::app);
    inputData1.open("Test1.txt",ios::app);
    string line;
    int count;
    while(getline(inputData1,line))
    {
        count++;
    }
    int hold[count],x;
    x=0;

    while(x<count)
    {
        inputData >> hold[x];
        x++;
    }
    x=0;
/*  while(x<count)
    {
        cout<<hold[x]<<"\n";
        x++;    
    }*/

    //BUBBLE SORT
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
        {
            int temp;
            if(j+1<count)
            {
                if(hold[j]>hold[j+1])
                {
                    temp = hold[j];
                    hold [j] = hold[j+1];
                    hold[j+1]= temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    while(x<count)
    {
        cout<<hold[x]<<"\n";
        x++;    
    }
```

Comment: Here Text1.txt is the file where i have saved the numbers. Also it is assumed that each number is entered in a seperate line.

Comment: Also if user is entering the file name then following code works                                      string name;                                                                                        getline(cin,name);                                                                                                             ifstream inputData(name);